# Moving ClickOnce VSTO To New Server

Tags: .net, vsto, clickonce, office-addins, comaddin

For a long time, I've published a VSTO to a certain server.  Let's call it ServerA.  So the publishing folder in Visual Studio is set to \ServerA\MyTool\install.

I now need to move the install to ServerB, but I don't want users to have to do anything to get the update (that's the point of ClickOnce, right?).

For non VSTOs Visual Studio give you the option to specify a different location to check for updates so I published a version to ServerA that said to look at ServerB for updates, and then I publish the new version to ServerB and that seems to all work.

For VSTOs, I can't find a place to tell the ClickOnce infrastructure to check an alternate location.  Does such a thing exist?  If not, any other ideas how to do this?

Comment: What option in non-VSTO projects allows specifying a different location to check for updates?

Comment: In Visual Studio Right Click the Project (not solution) --> Properties --> Publish Tab --> Updates --> Update Location (if different than publish location).